# Why is the wording for Stack Overflow Collectives™ on the about page different from the rest?

Tags: support, feature-request, status-declined, collectives

On the [Stack Overflow about page](https://stackoverflow.com/company) there are a bunch of boxes under "our products" which all start with the word "Where" (after the bold part), for example, it has the following text in the boxes:

> **Where** developers and technologists go to gain and share knowledge.

> **Where** developers and technologists go to share private knowledge with coworkers.

> **Where** companies build their employer brand to attract top tech talent.

> **Where** companies reach the world's largest audience of developers and technologists.

(Emphasis mine), these all start with the word "Where"

However, the box for Collectives™ says

> Connecting communities with the specific technologies they use the most.

With a distinct lack of the word "Where"

I think this should be changed to have better [parallel structure](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/mechanics/parallel_structure.html). One possible suggestion (though this suggestion might have other problems or incorrectly describe Collectives™ as I don't know a lot about it) is

> Where communities can connect with the specific technologies they use the most.

Actual questions:

So, was this wording intentional? And can it be changed?

Comment: I suspect that "companies" are supposed to be an implicit part of either the "communities" or the "specific technologies" bits mentioned in that statement. Thus, I think the equivalent would be something like "*Where communities can connect with the specific technologies they use the most*", no need to specifically mention "companies".

Comment: @zcoop98 sure, that was just a suggestion rewording, there might be (and probably are) better choices. My main point is that it should start with the word "where"

Comment: I mean... it's also a rather poor description of collectives in general. It's a tool for companies to reach the community, not a tool for the community to connect with technologies.

Comment: @KevinB that's a separate feature request. I don't know enough about Collectives™ to say wether or not the current description is accurate.

Comment: I assume they just didn't want to repeat the previous description, which does match collectives: `Where companies reach the world's largest audience of developers and technologists.`

Comment: @KevinB IMO there's likely some way to have it start with the word "Where" without it saying the same thing, but I might be wrong.

Comment: "interact with" rather than reach, maybe

Answer (score -8):

The wording choice was intentional and we don’t intend to change it at this time.

What makes  CollectivesTM different from the other products we offer is that it’s a place for users who regularly use specific technology to collaborate, and for the organizations who help build or maintain this technology to share their expertise. Questions and answers will continue to be curated by the Stack Overflow community, but the Collectives page will aggregate all of the relevant content, including articles, from the associated tags. Community members can join any Collectives page, participate in its leaderboard based on their contributions to its associated content, and find the users that are Admins or Recognized Members of a Collective (this information is included in [the announcement blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/06/23/collectives-stack-overflow/)).

So the product is about connecting people within a community to the technology they use the most.

Comment: I believe you may have missed the point. Either that, or I misunderstood. The way I read this feature request, Ekadh is not trying to criticize the *substance* of the Collectives branding. Rather, he's saying that you've established a very consistent theme of parallel structure, where all of the product taglines begin with "Where...", *except* for Collectives. Why not use that same parallel structure with Collectives for consistency? Maybe something like: *"Where communities connect with the specified technologies they use the most."*